# AutoScaling and Persistent TCP Connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2

Normally when you work with web applications auto scaling is something that's easily solved, especially with AutoScaling, ELB, Route53 etc.

However, with persistent TCP connections I find it harder to determine when to actually scale down. Scale up is pretty straight forward: define **when** and **how** and follow that protocol. But scaling down in an system that has long lived tcp connection opened seems to be more complicated, especially if your tcp server holds a certain state of the connected client. Which leaves me to the following question:

**How do you know when to scale down if you have live connections to your servers?**

Consider a setup where you have state dependent TCP servers behind a ELB (maybe in an AutoScaling Group), do you move to a more complicated Load Balancer solution or is this possible to achieve with what AWS has to offer?

Comment: You may be able to use Connection Draining on your load balancer for this case. If you scale down, it wont take an instance out of service until all connections have closed, or you have reached a timeout. But it will disallow new connections to the instance.

Comment: The timeout for connection draining can be a little short if you have game sessions running - but I guess it's just a matter of your CloudWatch alarm of when to scale down. Sloppy of me to not figure out the Connection Draining feature. Thank's for the response, this is the proper solution.

Comment: Elb will not wait for all the connections to drain, if deregisteration delay time reached and we have existing established connections, asg will still terminate the instance.